# Understanding naming conventions in Scala

Tags: scala, class, object, naming-conventions, traits

In scala, `object` and `trait` in the same scope can have the same name. But `class` and `trait` in the same scope cannot have the same name. Why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can think of a class and a trait as a *type*, and of an object as a *value*. You can always have a type and a value in the same scope without confusion:

```
trait Test {
  type X
  val X: Any
}
```

And the following won't work:

```
trait Test {
  type X
  trait X
}
```

This neither:

```
trait Test {
  object X
  val X: Any
}
```

The type of an object `X` is `X.type` (not `X`).

Comment: Basically, *Types* and *Terms* live in different worlds, and *Type Identifiers* (class and trait names, type parameters, type aliases) and *Value Identifiers* (objects, vals, vars, defs, method parameters, constructor parameters) live in separate namespaces. The two worlds only meet rarely, in path-dependent types, dependent method types, and singleton types, but even when they meet, they don't mix. Or, put another way: at any one point in a program, there can only ever occur a value identifier or a type identifier but never both.

Comment: Note that this is actually vital for Scala, because without it, there couldn't be companions: companions are a class/trait and an object with the same name in the same namespace, in the same compilation unit. Companions have privileged access to each other's internals.